# python import error in opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am getting this error when trying to import opencv:

```
>>> import cv2
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: opencv have dependencies please read official documentation

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running Numpy 1.7.

Upgrade to the latest (1.14 as of writing) and try again.